# Do the words дорогой (expensive) and дорога (road) have a common origin?

Tags: этимология

When learning a new language, I'm always looking for similarities between word roots - this helps me in remembering them. When learning Russian, I was surprised by the similarity of the words дорогой (expensive) and дорога (road). Do they have a common origin, or is this just a coincidence?

Comment: No, these words are of totally different roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are "dear" and "deer", or "drag" and "drug" related in English? No they are not. It's just happens sometime that some words sounds similar.

"Дорога" is related to "дёрн" (turf), "драть" (tear), "дёргать" and "дерево" (tree) and initially meant something like a path in a forest. Surprisingly, "дорога" is related to English verb drag.

[Here](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0) you can find out more:

> Происходит от индоевроп. *dorgh- (связано с дёргать и означает «продранное в лесу пространство»);

As of "дорогой", it's related to English word "dear", [here's](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dear) a quote:

> From Middle English *dere*, from Old English *dēore*, from Proto-Germanic
>   *diurijaz. Cognate with Dutch *duur* ‎(“costly, precious”), German teuer ‎(“costly, precious”), Icelandic *dýr* ‎(“expensive”), Norwegian *dyr*,
>   Swedish *dyr* ‎(“expensive”).

Comment: Are you sure драть and дерево are connected? I doubt it. Дерево comes from PIE doru "wood".

Comment: @Anixx as far as I know дерево <~> выдирать <~> драть

Comment: No. It comes from PIE doru and related to English "tree". See Vasmer.

Comment: Also, connection between dear and дорогой is doubtful, dear has unknown etymology.

Comment: @Anixx  nobody argues that  дерево  comes from  PIE root, it's the other way around, it's выдирать related to дерево
 Also, can you provide some evidence that "dear" is of unkown etymology?

Comment: If выдирать comes from dorgh- then it is unrelated to дерево because it comes from deru-. Etymology of dear http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dear What is your source to claim it is related to дорогой?

Comment: `some evidence that "dear" is of unkown etymology?` [Leiden Inda-European
Etymological Dictionary Series](http://www.bulgari-istoria-2010.com/Rechnici/A_Lyubotski_Proto_Germanik_dict.pdf): "***deurja-** adj. 'precious, valuable, expensive' - E. dear, G. teuer - No accepted etymology..."